# Notification of Workflow Suspension

Tags: 2013, workflow

Is there a way to retrieve a listing of all suspended workflows for a given site? For a list?

Even better, is there a way to have SharePoint send notification whenever a workflow suspends?

Answer (score 0):

For your custom workflows you can add OnError activity and handle the notifications,  for a list workflows,  you will have to comeup with a solution that iterates with the workflow instances and check the status for you.

Think about PowerShell if you have access to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited to SPD workflows, and I didn't see an OnError activity built into list workflows. I may look into getting the farm admin to lend me a hand with the PowerShell side. Thank you.

Comment: @Sudhir Kasharwani You wouldn't to happen have that PowerShell script that allowed this OnError notification or documentation? We are having a very similar issue.